# How much experience is needed to fill the gauge AFTER level 40?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

The bar no longer says the needed amount of experience. Trying to get skill points, but I don't know how much experience I need to fill it up each time.

Answer (score -4):

Level 40 is the max level.

If you want to get more skill points, you have to complete tombs and stuff.

Comment: Hi Angelo, welcome to the site! If you could explain how to earn Skill points without levelling in more detail this would be a better answer :). Which tombs would be best? What other 'stuff' can help you earn them?

Comment: While 40 is the max level (without DLC), you can keep filling the XP bar to get more skill points even if you're level-capped.